# How to map watson knowledge studio with content analytics?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

I am trying to export my analyzed documents collection from ICA to WKS but it says I have to do the mapping from UIMA type to Entity type of WKS. But I could not find any explanation of how should I proceed. 
Is there anyone who know what to do ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did this follow when I had this question a few weeks ago. I did the follow steps:

**Mapping UIMA types to entity types**

Before you import XMI files into a Watson Knowledge Studio project, you must define mappings between the UIMA types and Watson Knowledge Studio entity types.

**Before you begin**

The type system in your Watson Knowledge Studio project must include the entity types that you want to map the UIMA types to.

**To map UIMA types to WKS entity types:**

1. Create a file named `cas2di.tsv` in the folder that contains the UIMA TypeSystem descriptor file, such as `exported_typesystem.xml` or `TypeSystem.xml`.
2. Open the `cas2di.tsv` file with a text editor. Each line in the file specifies a single mapping. The format of the mapping depends on which annotator's annotations you want to map:

You can create mappings by using the basic format:

```
UIMA_Type_Name[TAB]WKS_Entity_Type
```

The following example defines mappings between UIMA types produced by the *Named Entity Recognition* annotator in IBM Watson Explorer Content Analytics and entity types defined in a WKS type system:

```
com.ibm.langware.Organization  ORGANIZATION
com.ibm.langware.Person  PERSON
com.ibm.langware.Location  LOCATION
```

Another example defines a mapping between UIMA types produced by custom annotator that was created in IBM Watson Explorer Content Analytics Studio and Watson Knowledge Studio entity types:

```
com.ibm.Person  PERSON
com.ibm.Date  DATE
```

You can create mappings based on facets that are used in the Pattern Matcher annotator or Dictionary Lookup annotator in Watson Explorer Content Analytics. In text analysis rule files (*.pat), the facet is represented as the category attribute. To define a mapping, use the following syntax:

```
com.ibm.takmi.nlp.annotation_type.ContiguousContext:category=FACET_PATH[TAB]WKS_ENTITY_TYPE
```

Like:

```
com.ibm.takmi.nlp.annotation_type.ContiguousContext:category=FACET_PATH[TAB]ORGANIZATION
```

See the [Official Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/wks/wks_uima.shtml).

Comment: Okay, I did the same and works perfectly... Let's check your problem, can you please edit with what you try, and with the errors?

Comment: A file could not be imported: Cannot import annotated documents because the type system is not defined. You must import the type system from the same original project before you import annotated documents. Check whether the documents are in UIMA CAS XMI format. (You selected 'Import documents in UIMA CAS XMI format')

Comment: try to convert to `.xmi`

Comment: it is done, :) the problem was in the empty .xmi files. And the too heavy ones.